# Speed up distance calculations, FFT, Sliding window

Tags: algorithms, convolution, python, fast-fourier-transform

I have two time series A and B. A with length `m` and B with length `n`. `m << n`. Both have the dimension `d`.

I calculate the distance between A and all subsequencies in B by sliding A over B. 
In python the code looks like this.

```
def sliding_dist(A,B)
    n = len(B)
    dist = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n-m):
        subrange = B[i:i+m,:]
        distance = np.linalg.norm(A-subrange)
        dist[i] = distance
    return dist
```

Now this code takes a lot of time to execute and I have very many calculations to do. 
I need to speed up the calculations. My guess is that I could do this by using convolutions, and multiplication in frequency domain. However, I have been unable to implement it.

Any ideas? :) Thanks